# Y axis inversion in 3D rasterization

Tags: 3d, projections, rasterizer

What is the correct way to invert the y axis during the 3D projection?

I see a lot a people doing:

```c
pixel_x = (x_world / z_world + 1) / 2 * ScreenWidth(); // This is right
pixel_y = (1 - y_world / z_world) / 2 * ScreenHeight();
```

But by inverting like this, we get an incorrect position of `pixel_y` because what this does is saying that `pixel_y` is 1 when `y_world` is -1 and 1 when `y_world` is -1. This seems right but don't forget that a point at `x == 1` in NDC space will map to `pixel_x = ScreenWidth()` and therefore won't be visible. In contrast, a point at `x == -1` in NDC space will map to `pixel_x = 0` and WILL be visible.
So if we invert like this, a point at `y == -1` will become `pixel_y == ScreenHeight()` and WON'T be visible but a point at `y == 1` will become `pixel_y == 0` and will be visible.

I think that the correct way of inverting y is by first calculating `pixel_y` like `pixel_x` and then and only then invert it in pixel space:

```
pixel_y = (y_world / z_world + 1) / 2 * ScreenHeight(); // Y points up
pixel_y = ScreenHeight() - 1 - pixel_y; // now it points down
```

So what is the correct way to invert the y axis during the projection?

Comment: Right way to do that is setting the values directly on points (vertices) or using rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your formula:

```
pixel_y = (y_world / z_world + 1) / 2 * ScreenHeight();
pixel_y = ScreenHeight() - 1 - pixel_y;
```

Let's call `y_world / z_world` for short `a`, `H` for `ScreenHeight()`. So you have:

```
Y = (a + 1) / 2 *H
Y = H - 1 - Y
```

Let's replace the first in the second:

```
   Y = H - 1 - (a + 1) / 2 * H
=> Y = H * (1 - (a + 1) / 2) - 1
=> Y = H * ((2 - a - 1) / 2) - 1
=> Y = H * (1 - a) / 2 - 1
```

Which is the formula you said every one uses (except with an off-by-one error):

```
pixel_y = (1 - y_world / z_world) / 2 * ScreenHeight();
```

Off-by-one error aside, looks like you have the right understanding, just didn't work out that the formula everyone uses is the optimized version of what you came up with.